# How can I configure unix:///var/run/docker.sock to point to a remote host?

Tags: vpn, docker, mac-osx, docker-machine

I know I can build and run a container on a remote host with Docker Machine, but some tools I'm using have built-in reliance on `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`, so even if I run `eval $(docker-machine env my_remote_machine)` first, the fool fails with the standard:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? :unable to build some_image docker image`

Can I make something like a symbolic link so `docker.sock` points to my remote Docker Machine?  Or can I configure my local docker somehow so that all "local" docker activity really happens remotely?   I'm running Docker Desktop on MacOS 10.14.4 which currently requires spinning up a VM to run Docker anyways, so maybe I can configure it so that VM is on a remote host?

**Extra Credit**
Where this gets more tricky is: my local machine is on a corp VPN where I can pull Artifactory images.  The remote Docker Machine I'd like to use is not on the same VPN, but is on the same local network as my local machine, so I may have to set my local machine to be a proxy for my remote docker machine so that it can pull the Artifactory images.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Expose a tcp socket for accessing docker API

https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/socat/